# Java(TM) platform SE binary is still active after I kill the process

Tags: maven, python-3.x, jvm, subprocess, kill

I used to execute CMDs command inside python using `subprocess`, and my partial code is as follows.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("mvn test", shell = True)
try:
    proc.wait(60)  # set timeout of proc
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()  # kill the proc if it timed out
    print("subprocess is killed")
```

It do will kill the subprocess after ***proc.kill()***, but the side-effect comes, **Java(TM) Platform SE binary** is still active and take much resource of my computer.So how can I finally kill the **Java(TM) Platform SE binary**?
I just supposed that command `mvn test` will call the JVM(something like that), when I kill the process `proc`, the **Java(TM) Platform SE binary** isn't be killed. 
[Picture of Windows Resource Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nThFm.jpg)

Comment: I just afried that the process `Java(TM) Platform SE binary` will become the isolated process and take too much computer resources :( **WHO CAN HELP ME**

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

Comment: @bert Thanks for your help, But when I use `os.killgp(os.getgpid(proc.pid), signal.SIGTERM)` on WINDOWS plarform, It will throw exception that `module os has no attribute of 'killgp'`, maybe I should search more for my problem.

Comment: @bert FFFFFinally, I have to kill all the children process the `proc` has generated by kill the `proc` on WINDOWS command **taskkill**. Oh, whish all is well. Thank you all the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having tried some other functions such as `subprocess.run`, `subprocess.call` and so on, all are failed to kill the child process generated by **proc** on WINDOWS. Maybe these functions still only work for LINUX.

So I finally use WINDOWS command `taskkill` to kill the subprocess (i.e., **proc**), my final codes are as follows and the **Java(TM) Platform SE binary** is killed after I kill **proc**,

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("mvn test", shell = True)
try:
    proc.wait(60)  # set timeout of proc
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    # kill the proc if it timed out
    subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/T", "/PID", str(proc.pid)], shell = True)  
    print("subprocess is killed")
```

Comment: This or a similar issue has been fixed in maven-surefire-plugin ("maven test") as of version 2.19. See the [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-524).

Comment: Hi, @EvgeniSergeev ,thanks for your suggestion, maybe the latest sure-fire plugin fixed this bug. Besides, I have blamed this bug to python language before, but if we can solve this problem by fixing the plugin, thing becomes easy.